# AzureWebJobsDashboard Configuration Error

Tags: c#, azure, connection-string, azure-webjobs, azure-webjobssdk

I created a new Azure WebJob project in Visual Studio 2015 using .NET Framework 4.6.

In the app.config, I set three connection strings:

1. AzureWebJobsDashboard
2. AzureWebJobsStorage
3. MyDatabaseConnectionString

The AzureWebJobsDashboard and AzureWebJobsStorage connection strings are identical and they're both pointing to my storage account. I'm including one of the connection strings -- since they're both identical, except the "name".

```
<add name="AzureWebJobsDashboard" connectionString="DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=mystorageaccountname;AccountKey=thisIsTheLongPrimaryKeyICopiedFromAzurePortalForMyStorageAccount" />
```

Everything looks right to me but I'm getting the following error:

> The configuration is not properly set for the Microsoft Azure WebJobs
>   Dashboard.  In your Microsoft Azure Website configuration you must set
>   a connection string named AzureWebJobsDashboard by using the following
>   format DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=NAME;AccountKey=KEY
>   pointing to the Microsoft Azure Storage account where the Microsoft
>   Azure WebJobs Runtime logs are stored.

By the way, I know the app.config is being read by the web job because my code is able to connect to my database and update some records.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 60, accepted):

You need to set the **AzureWebJobsDashboard** connection string in the portal in your Web App Application Settings blade (steps to do that [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-configure/)). The Dashboard runs as a separate site extension and doesn't have access to app.config. Add the connection string to the **connection strings** section on the settings blade.

You can add your other connection strings there as well (e.g. **AzureWebJobsStorage**) rather than storing in app.config if you wish for security/consistency, however the WebJob can read AzureWebJobsStorage from app.config.

Comment: That's exactly what the issue was. Added the AzureWebJobsDashboard to the Application Settings through Azure Portal and everything works like a charm. Thank you so much Matthew!

Comment: I test to add in web.config of Web App and It didn't work.

Comment: Currently, we have to put value at Portal > Application Settings > Connectionstring manually. This seems by-design behavior. Detailed description is here; https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk/issues/589#issuecomment-151648354

Comment: I haven't seen what type the connection string should be, specified anywhere, so I added the two connection strings in Application Settings with a type of **custom** and that worked. The error and warning messages disappeared and the UI contained webjob history.

Comment: I have added connectionString manually thru portal->App Settings with Custom type, but it still does not work :(

Answer (score 3):

The change needs to be done in App Services settings in Azure Portal

For that

1. Open the Azure (Management) Portal at https://portal.azure.com
2. Goto Home > *App Services*
3. Select the App service that is hosting your WebJob
4. Goto Settings > Choose *Application settings*
5. Scroll down to *Connection strings*
6. Add a new connection string with Name as 'AzureWebJobsDashboard' and Value as  . Choose Type as 'Custom'
7. Press Save Button ( at the Page Top)

All done!  Check your Webjobs Dashboard - the Warning and Error message at top should be gone now.

Answer (score 2):

I was having this problem too.

My storageaccount kind is `StorageV2 (general purpose V2)`

I had both `AzureWebJobsDashboard` and `AzureWebJobsStorage` correctly set in the App Service Configuration.

But, the storage account had a `Minimum TLS version` set to `1.2`

I found that changing this to `1.0` was needed for the WebJobs Dashboard to display correctly and for the WebJobs to run ok.

Comment: Haha, good spot, I never would have guessed that.

Answer (score 0):

Right now (version of Web Job Tools is 15.0.31201.0) no necessary to configure any connection strings from azure portal, enough to set it in app.config file of web job