# WebJobs - The configuration is not properly set for the Microsoft Azure WebJobs Dashboard

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-storage, azure-webjobs

I created a web job, deployed it. Got an error:

> The configuration is not properly set for the Microsoft Azure WebJobs
>   Dashboard.  In your Microsoft Azure Website configuration you must set
>   a connection string named AzureWebJobsDashboard by using the following
>   format DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=NAME;AccountKey=KEY
>   pointing to the Microsoft Azure Storage account where the Microsoft
>   Azure WebJobs Runtime logs are stored.

I have read this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34125299/285336 that I have to add AzureWebJobsDashboard as connection string via portal.

I did it:
[image]

(I sure, that I use https protocol)
[image]

saved, restarted application. But error is the same! Why so and how to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was in my code (which was a dummy for that moment), but by unknown reason the error about AzureWebJobsDashboard shown (even when AzureWebJobsDashboard is set). When I fixed my error I see the following page:

[image]

so, as we can see, web job is completed successfully, but "fake" error about AzureWebJobsDashboard is shown.

Also, there are no necessary to configure any connection strings via portal at all. For now, it's enough to set it in app.config. Version of Web Job Tools is 15.0.31201.0